# SQL Server breaks the assigned identity seed increment?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication, identity

I have two tables: `table1` (column `id`: Seed 1000, increment 1) & `table2` (column `id`: Seed 2000, increment 1). First I insert some records in `table1` & `table2`. Second I insert to `table2` in `table1` (using `identity_insert_on`) and get something like:

```
1000 first_record_table1
1001 second_record_table1
1002 third_record_table1
2000 first_record_table2
2001 second_record_table2
```

Third: If I add a new record in table1, i expect to get 1003 as the new id but i get 2002. 
(1003 is not breaking the unique id rule and is the correct increment value for table1, so I don't see any reason to jump to the last record and increment 1, as the database seems to do).

Question: How can I get 1003 as the new id?

Comment: is it sql server 2012 ???

Comment: if you are doing inserts with idnetity_insert set on you should not be using iddentity, you have completely misunderstood what an autogenerated key is.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) on `identity` is quite clear:

> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> - Uniqueness of the value – Uniqueness must be enforced by using a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint or UNIQUE index.
> - Consecutive values within a transaction – A transaction inserting    multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock on the table or use the SERIALIZABLE isolation level.
> - Consecutive values after server restart or other failures –SQL Server might cache identity values for performance reasons and some of the assigned values can be lost during a database failure or server restart. This can result in gaps in the identity value upon insert.  If gaps are not acceptable then the application should use a sequence generator with the NOCACHE option or use their own mechanism to generate key values.
> - Reuse of values – For a given identity property with specific    seed/increment, the identity values are not reused by the engine. If a particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not be generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent identity values are generated.

In most cases, an `identity primary key` column does just what it is intended to do.  It creates a new value bigger than any previous value when a new row is inserted.  There may be gaps, but that is not a problem for a primary key.

If you want a column that fills in gaps, then you will have to write a trigger to assign the values.

Alternatively, you could just use `row_number()` in queries to get sequential values.

Comment: there will be gaps for any records that are rolled back as well as any delted. This is by design an is part of what allows it to effectively aurogenerate the ids. You should never expect the autogenerated key to not skip numberss. Nor does it make sense to care if numbers are skipped, autogenerated keys are supposed to be without meaning.

Comment: I understand that seed is used only for the first record and max(id) is used for any other record? Trying to map a rule.

Comment: @user2934862 . . . `max(id)+1` may not be used for the next id.  The next id might be larger.  SQL Server reserves the right to "reserve" more than 1 id at a time, even if all of them are not used.

Answer (score 1):

Increment 1 just means the next record will have an ID that's one larger than the largest one, not that all numbers will be used. If you want the 1003 as the new ID, you'll have to do some programming yourself, and handle the case that the new is already taken once you reach 2000.

But you should never ever rely on any generated IDs being without gaps. Imagine you have 2 sessions. First session inserts something and does not commit nor rollback yet. Second session inserts something and commits. First session rolls back. How do you want to handle this case? You will need to assign some ID to the first session, and a different ID to the second one. Now the first session rolls back, so its ID is unused. Do you want to subtract one from the second session's ID? Very bad idea. Block the 2nd session until the 1st one has either rolled back or committed? Very bad idea as well.

So please forget about consecutive IDs, they will never work. Unique IDs are what you normally need, and SQL Server guarantees them.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Gaps was not my concern: It was about why the database engine break the "seed...increment" rule BEFORE a conflict appears. looks like seed is used only for the first record and max(id) is used for any other record